# Convert JSON to dataframe with two indices

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert some financial data provided in JSON format into a single row in a dataframe.  However, this JSON has the data with two indices or nested indices?  I'm not sure how to appropriately describe the data.

So below is the code I'm using to pull the financial data.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
stock ='AAPL'
BS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/balance-sheet-statement/{stock}?period=quarter")
data = BS.json()
```

The output looks like this

```
{'symbol': 'AAPL',
 'financials': [{'date': '2019-12-28',
   'Cash and cash equivalents': '39771000000.0',
   'Short-term investments': '67391000000.0',
   'Cash and short-term investments': '1.07162e+11',
   'Receivables': '20970000000.0',...}
```

I've tried the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

and

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data), orient='columns')
```

Neither gets me what I want.  Somehow I need to get rid of 'financials'.  I want the data frame to 
look like:
[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just use the dict of `'financials'` when creating the dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
stock ='AAPL'
BS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/balance-sheet-statement/{stock}?period=quarter")
data = BS.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['financials'])
print(df)
```